# Append Link description to mp3s downloaded using wget

Tags: curl, cross-domain, href, rename, wget

I spent the last 30 minutes figuring out how to download mp3s from a site that has its content stored on a different domain.

Using the command, I got it to download just the mp3s with no directory structure, and it worked fine:

wget -pkEHnd --domains=campnegotiationinstitute.com,startwithno.com -r --level=0 -A '*.mp3' www.campnegotiationinstitute.com/pnewcj9d

I'd like a way to append to the non-descriptive filename, the description on the page for each file, as the filename are non-descrepyt. This is a problem I and am sure others often encounter when ripping content for offline use.

So instead of getting a filename

01_02.mp3

for example,  I would get

01_02-The birth of the system.mp3

Basically using the href description, between a tags.
I'm fairly certain a script might be in order here to do the parsing and renaming.
Hope that makes sense.